# Jquery - dropdown menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor, cascadingdropdown

I am relatively new to jquery and I am seeking help. The aim is to click on a list item attached to a ul and have it appear whilst any other list items disappear. Only the active one is viewable

The Issue I am having is that when I click on another list item the active one disappears (as intended), but it doesn't reveal the other one, it remains hidden. I am looking for a way to reveal the list, while hiding the ones that are in-active.

I have uploaded my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/CbU4d/

html:

```
<div id="secondary-nav"><!--secondary-nav-->    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#.html">Current Article</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#.html">Example 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#.html">Past Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#.html">Example 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#.html">Example 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#.html">Example 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div><!--/secondary-nav-->
```

css:

```
#secondary-nav {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:23%; /*210px*/
    border-right:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
}

/*heading styles*/
#secondary-nav ul li {
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#secondary-nav ul li a {
    font-family:TrajanPro;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height: 32px;
    color:#000;
}

/*links*/
#secondary-nav ul ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-family:TrajanPro;
    font-size:0.9em;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}

#secondary-nav ul li a:hover {
    display:block;
    color:#af2931;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#secondary-nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#secondary-nav li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
/css
```

jquery using 1.7.1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#secondary-nav ul").click(function(){
        //slide up all the link lists
        $("#secondary-nav ul ul").slideUp();
        //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$("#secondary-nav ul ul").slideToggle();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prash/CbU4d/1/)

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work (I think) by making two changes:

1. Change the selector on line 2 to this:

   ```
   "#secondary-nav ul li"
   ```

   This means the event will be attached to the list item you click, not the entire list.
2. Remove the if statement on line 6. Since we're hiding **all** of the second level `ul`s in the previous line, we don't need to check if it's visible; we know it isn't.
3. Change line 6 to this:

   ```
   $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
   ```

   This is because the `ul` you want to unfold is a child of the `li` you're clicking, not a sibling.

[Here's my fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nk7rs/).

Edit: If you want to stop it from hiding and re-showing when you click the one that's already expanded, just chuck this at the top of the handler:

```
if ($(this).children('ul').is(':visible')){
    return
}
```